# I try to make an infinite carousel jquery with the shortest Jquery code

Tags: jquery, carousel

I try to make an carousel using less jquery code, the problem is when the page is refreshed it start without picture other way it won't work. There is eny other solution to what i did ?

```js
var x = 0;
var y = -1;
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#next").click(function(){
  x = ++x;
  y = ++y;
  if (x == 8 || y==7){
   x=0;
   y=-1;
  }else{
  }
     $("img:eq("+x+")").addClass("animatie");
            
            $("img:eq("+y+")").removeClass("animatie");
 })
})
```

```css
body{
    
} 
.slide {
 display:none;
    
}
.animatie {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 display:block;
}
#slider{
 background-color:red;
 width:100%;
 height:75%;
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
 <img class="slide" src="images/basketball.jpg"/>
 <img class="slide" src="images/bicycle.jpg"/>
 <img class="slide" src="images/bungalows.jpg"/>
 <img class="slide" src="images/celebrations.jpg"/>
 <img class="slide" src="images/mountain.jpg"/>
 <img class="slide" src="images/rainy.jpg"/>
 <img class="slide" src="images/runner.jpg"/>
 <img class="slide" src="images/unnamed.jpg"/>
</div>
```